# How do I change a github page to run from a forked repo?

Tags: github, github-pages

I create a github page under my personal account.
Then, I created an organzation, and forked this repository.

Now, I would like the github page to be served from the forked copy, not the original.

How do I change the "live" repository that is the source of the github page?

(Both have the same CNAME record file)

Comment: You can transfer the ownership of your repository to the organization, and then make a personal fork.  I think, this would make it clear that the repository of the organization is the "official" repository, to your users; along with fixing your problem. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @punchagan - yeah, that's what I did, and it solved my issue. Still, I'm confused as to how github pages work with forks. Does the parent fork always override the forks?

Comment: I'm not sure how GitHub handles forks for this case. Also, I guess you can mark this question as answered, if you problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe github pages works on a "first come, first serve" basis to custom domains.

Possible solutions:

1. Delete the original repository and try to push CNAME to the new one / rebuilding the github page somehow. Perhaps github will pick the new custom domain once it understands the old repo isn't using it anymore (it might take some time to refresh)
2. **The easy way out** - delete the new repository, and simple transfer the original repository to the organization.